# Riding in the mountains, swimming in the seas

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> Riding in the mountains,
> swimming in the seas,
> traveling to the farlands,
> yet staying home and eating cheese.
>
> Could it be a mouse,
> or could it be rat?
> Perhaps we'll never know,
> or perhaps you'll find out slow.

**What am I?**

Comment: Is this your original puzzle? if not please attribute a source to this.

Comment: @PrinceDeepthinker yes, i came up with this. And yes again, it has a logical answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I say

> the French.

This is because:

> The French can travel to their mountains. They also have long coastlines on the Atlantic ocean and the Mediterranean, where they swim in the seas. The French have significant areas of farmland, where they farm, raise animals, or vacation. The French produce the largest variety of cheeses, which they can eat in all these places, and throughout the country, at home in France.